# Selenium number of lines in a table?

Tags: python, selenium, count, html-table, lines

I have this structure :

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr id="1_2011_11_11_07_45_00" class="on">
    </tr>
    <tr id="1_2011_11_11_09_25_00">
    </tr>
    <tr id="1_2011_11_11_11_05_00">
    </tr>
    <tr id="1_2011_11_11_14_50_00">
    </tr>
    <tr id="1_2011_11_11_16_00_00">
    </tr>
    <tr id="1_2011_11_11_18_10_00">
    </tr>
    <tr id="1_2011_11_11_21_30_00">
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

and I would like to count the number of lines that are in the table. I am using Python for the script.
The xpath of the table is :

xpath=/html/body/form/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/table

Anyone could help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can also be done via get_xpath_count.
for ex. Number_of_row = $browser.get_xpath_count("/tbody/tr")

I have not checked the above code but I think it will work

Comment: Great Thank you ! however in my page 2 tables have almost the same Xpath, the other one has :
xpath=/html/body/form/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/table
and it takes the count of both,i don't know why

Comment: Its might be because the xpath_count of "/tbody" be 2. Hence taking the "tr" count for both the "/tbody". Try giving the absolute xpath for the table you want to count

Answer (score 0):

```
s = """<table>
<tbody>
    <tr id="1_2011_11_11_07_45_00" class="on">
    </tr>
    <tr id="1_2011_11_11_09_25_00">
    </tr>
    <tr id="1_2011_11_11_11_05_00">
    </tr>
    <tr id="1_2011_11_11_14_50_00">
    </tr>
    <tr id="1_2011_11_11_16_00_00">
    </tr>
    <tr id="1_2011_11_11_18_10_00">
    </tr>
    <tr id="1_2011_11_11_21_30_00">
    </tr>
</tbody>"""
import re
len(re.findall('\tr',s))
```

Answer (score 0):

Xpath contains a count(<node-set expr>) function.

Simplifying your example, if your table were the only table in the html source, then the
the xpath expression 
count(//table//tr)
would return the number 7.